# A detail in the proof of Banach-Steinhaus theorem that I don't understand

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am studying functional analysis and I have seen the Banach-Steinhaus
theorem.

For starters, the motivation given was the question about when $\{T_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$
are bounded by $M$ (here the linear operators are $T_{\alpha}:X\to Y$).

The proof given was:

> Define  $$ F_{n}:=\{x\in X\mid||T_{\alpha}x||\leq n\,\forall\alpha\} $$
>
> Then by the assumption that the operators are pointwise bounded we get
>   $$ X=\cup_{n}F_{n} $$
>
> By Baire category theorem there is $n$ s.t $F_{n}$ contains a ball
>   $B_{\epsilon}^{X}(x_{0})$.
>
> Pick $\alpha$.  $$
>  T_{\alpha}(B_{\epsilon}^{X}(x_{0})-B_{\epsilon}^{X}(x_{0}))\subseteq
>  B_{2n}^{Y}(0) $$
>
> Hence  $$ ||T_{\alpha}||\leq2n\cdot\frac{1}{\epsilon} $$

Can someone please explain the "Hence" part at the end ?

So all $T_{\alpha}$ map some subset of $X$ to a bounded ball of
a fixed radius $2n$, how did we bound $T_{\alpha}$ for all $x\in X$
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\|y\| < 1$ then $\varepsilon y = (x_0+\varepsilon y) -x_0 \in B_{\varepsilon}^X(x_0) - B_{\varepsilon}^X(x_0)$, hence $\|T_{\alpha}y\| = \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}\|T_{\alpha}(\varepsilon y)\| \leqslant \dfrac{2n}{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Don't we have to consider $||y||=1$ too ?

Comment: By linearity of $T$ we have $\sup_{\|x\|<1} \|Tx\|= \sup_{\|x\|\leqslant 1} \|Tx\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Tx\|$.

Comment: emm, Is it linearity or continuity for this ? (or maybe both) (thanks for the help)

Comment: Linearity is enough. But if you are not comfortable with $<$ then write $\varepsilon y = (x_0+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2} y)-(x_0-\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2} y)$ for $\|y\| \leqslant 1$.